# Htaccess Redirect an ID Query String URL to User Friendly URL

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I am trying to redirect a page with an ID querty string in it to a user friendly URL. I have multiple pages like this that I need to redirect within the htaccess file. Here is an example of one of the pages I am trying to redirect:

Old URL:
`examplepage.com/about_news_info.aspx?id=275`

redirect to

New URL:
`examplepage.com/news-events/`

This is what I am using with no luck:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^id=275$
RewriteRule ^/about_news_info.aspx http://examplepage.com/news-events/test1 [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^cateid=373$
RewriteRule ^/about_news.aspx http://examplepage.com/news-events/test2 [L,R=301]
```

Answer (score 1):

.htaccess is `per directory` context vs putting it in the config file so your pattern is not matching.

From the documentation:

> When using the rewrite engine in .htaccess files the per-directory
>   prefix (which always is the same for a specific directory) is
>   automatically removed for the RewriteRule pattern matching and
>   automatically added after any relative (not starting with a slash or
>   protocol name) substitution encounters the end of a rule set. See the
>   RewriteBase directive for more information regarding what prefix will
>   be added back to relative substitutions.
>
> The removed prefix always ends with a slash, meaning the matching
>   occurs against a string which never has a leading slash. **Therefore,
>   a Pattern with ^/ never matches in per-directory context.**

So your rules should look like this **without** the leading `/` in the RewriteRule.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^id=275$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^about_news_info.aspx http://examplepage.com/news-events/test1 [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^cateid=373$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^about_news.aspx http://examplepage.com/news-events/test2 [L,R=301]
```

Without checking for query string which really isn't needed.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^about_news_info.aspx$ http://examplepage.com/news-events/test1? [L,R=301]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^about_news.aspx$ http://examplepage.com/news-events/test2? [L,R=301]
```

Comment: I tried the code you provided but the URL is still not redirecting and going to a 404 page.

Comment: I'm curious where is the .htaccess code at that you have aspx pages? That is typically ran on an IIS server not apache.

Comment: This site was on a windows server, but is now on an apache server and I want all the old URLs to redirect to the new pages so that we do not get an increase in not found pages from Google Webmaster Tools.

Comment: You don't need to worry about the query string. Just make sure the file matches and it will redirect regardless of the query string. See my updated code.

Comment: There are multiple query strings per URL. For example there is examplepage.com/about_news_info.aspx?id=275 and examplepage.com/about_news_info.aspx?id=325 that each go to a separate page. So I will need to specify the query string. I appreciate your help.

Comment: @jadero I updated the code again. Try the first code I put with the query string conditions. Clear your cache before trying the updated code.

Comment: Thank you! I removed the REQUEST_FILENAME, but adding the $ after the .aspx and the ? after the redirect URL made it work.

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^id=275$
RewriteRule ^about_news_info.aspx$ http://examplepage.com/news-events/test1? [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^cateid=373$
RewriteRule ^about_news.aspx$ http://examplepage.com/news-events/test2? [L,R=301]
```